# How to convert a specific string to integer?

Tags: php, datetime

Hi here is the scenario that I have strings like this;

```
$a="08";
$b="00";
$c="0";
```

actually this is time part of a `datetime` i want to get these as **integer**

Comment: What do you want to achieve (on the long run)? You can cast `(int)$a` or use http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Answer (score 1):

You can simply typecast them like so:

```
$a=(int)"08";
$b=(int)"00";
$c=(int)"0";
```

As suggested by @Stan Winiecki
An explicit typecast may help you go for:

```
 $seconds = (int)$a * 3600
```

Comment: i am trying like this `$seconds=(int)$a*3600;` and `$seconds` is empty

Comment: `08` might be treated as octal because of the leading zero; and `8` isn't a valid octal digit.... strip leading zeroes before casting to int

Comment: That can't be this is the var_dump of $a = "08" is` int(8)`

Comment: If dump of a$ (="08") is int(8) then it casts to integer automatically. I would suggest to put spaces where they should be, like this: $seconds = a$ * 3600  (without casting) or  $seconds = (int)$a * 3600  (with explicit casting) and see what you get. Because I'm getting 28800...

Comment: Thanks @StanWiniecki this info help me a lot

Comment: I will update my answer as suggested by @StanWiniecki

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do this because PHP will handle it by itself.
If you want to explicitly convert it you can use

```
$int = (int)$a;
```

Answer (score 0):

It'a simple as casting your variables to integer:

```
$a =(int)$a;
```

But, since php is loosely typed, it will usually take care of the type conversion behind the scenes.

Comment: @MudassarZahid - Don't simply say "not working for me"; explain why it isn't working; what you expect, what you actually get.... we're trying to help you, but don't want to have to guess what you see on your screen

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$n="19.99";
print intval($n*100); // prints 1998
print intval(strval($n*100)); // prints 1999
?>
```

Use something like this.

Answer (score 0):

For situations where you do want to explicitly convert the type, [cast](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) it:

```
$a="08";
$b="00";
$c="0";
$seconds=(int)$a*3600;
var_dump((int)$a);
print_r($seconds);
```

Hope it helps!